# Need help in writing Test Class for Rest API Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I have a REST API class which updates the user status in external system when the user status is changed in Salesforce. Below is the code

```
public class AccUpdateController {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void AccupdateController(Set<Id> accountIdset) {       
        string resultBodyGet = '';

        list<Account> accts = [SELECT Unique_ID__c, Account_Status__c, Email__c from Account where Account_Partner_Status__c = 'ACTIVE' and Id IN:accountIdset];

        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + accts);        
        for(Account c : accts){         

            MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
            tags.put('accId', c.Unique_ID__c);
            tags.put('email', c.Email__c);
            tags.put('status', c.Account_Status__c);            
            system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(tags));            
            try{
                string endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint.com';
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                req.setbody(JSON.serialize(tags));
                Http http = new Http();
                system.debug('Sending User to update status');
                HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
                system.debug('Status updated');
                resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
                system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
                accResponse myAccResponse = new accResponse();
                myAccResponse = (accResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, accResponse.class);
                system.debug('#### myAccResponse: ' + myAccResponse);

            }
            catch (exception e) {                              
            }   
        }
    }    
    public class accResponse {
        public string message {get;set;}
    }
}
```

I have a trigger which triggers the callout when a status is changed in Salesforce. It is as below

```
trigger AccUpdateTrigger on Account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account accObj: trigger.new){
        if(accObj.Unique_ID__c  != trigger.oldmap.get(accObj.id).Unique_ID__c){
            accountIdSet.add(accObj.id);
        }
    }
    if(!accountIdSet.isEmpty()){
        AccUpdateController.AccupdateController(accountIdSet);
    }
}
```

I have written a test class to cover the above code but I'm getting the coverage as 0%. Below is the code

```
@istest
public class AccClassHTTPPost{

    static testMethod void  updateMethodTest(){

        Account TestAcc = new Account();
        TestAcc.Unique_ID__c = '0000000';
        TestAcc.Name = 'Test Account';
        TestAcc.Account_Status__c = 'Active';
        TestAcc.Email__c = 'Test@gmail.com';
        TestAcc.Account_Partner_Status__c = 'Active';
        insert TestAcc;
        AccUpdateController reqst = new AccUpdateController();
        //String JsonMsg=JSON.serialize(reqst);
        Test.startTest();

         String endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint.com';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setbody(JSON.serialize(reqst));
        update TestAcc;
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest where did it went wrong in my test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skumar. Thanks for the question. Please rewrite your test class like this:

```
@istest
public class AccClassHTTPPost{

static testMethod void  updateMethodTest(){

    Account TestAcc = new Account();
    TestAcc.Unique_ID__c = '0000000';
    TestAcc.Name = 'Test Account';
    TestAcc.Account_Status__c = 'Active';
    TestAcc.Email__c = 'Test@gmail.com';
    TestAcc.Account_Partner_Status__c = 'Active';
    insert TestAcc;
    AccUpdateController reqst = new AccUpdateController();
    //String JsonMsg=JSON.serialize(reqst);
    Test.startTest();

     String endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint.com';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    req.setbody(JSON.serialize(reqst));

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    Set<Id> idsSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account acc : accList)
        idsSet.add(acc.Id);        
    AccUpdateController.AccupdateController(idsSet);

    Test.stopTest();

    update TestAcc;

}
}
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton @artur. My controller is covered to 82%. I have updated my question with the trigger I have which triggers the actual functionality. When I have ran the test class which you've provided, it has covered the trigger 66%. Could you please suggest any way to get trigger code covered as well

Comment: "Code dump" answers, which do not contain any explanation, provide limited value to the community and the asker, and tend to lead to a lot of back-and-forth in the comments. Instead of pasting code, please describe the issue and how it can be solved, including code to support the solution.

Comment: @David Reed Sorry, I'm only recently began study salesforce and, in truth, don't understand all features of language. I'll try to give a detailed answer soon, but< if you can help me with it, I'll be grateful.